# Error Number: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting this error while joining two tables in codeigniter.

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near '.`id = a`.`assignee_key where a`.`assigned_to="office" and
user`.`id="53"`' at line 1
```

```
select a`.* from address as `a LEFT JOIN user ON user`.`id = a`.`assignee_key where a`.`assigned_to="office" and user`.`id="53"

$this->db->select('select a.* from address as a LEFT JOIN  user  ON  user.id = a.assignee_key where a.assigned_to="office" and user.id="'.$user_id.'"');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `AS` I guess.

Comment: seems you are missing left  ` around table name..  \`table_name\`.\`column_name\`

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in alias table name. Try this

```
$this->db->select('select a.* from address a LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = a.assignee_key where a.assigned_to="office" and u.id="'.$user_id.'"');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
```

Comment: Thanks, but still i am getting error:   Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`assignee_key where a`.assigned_to="office" and `u`.`id="53"`' at line 1

SELECT `select a`.`* from address a LEFT JOIN user u ON u`.`id = a`.`assignee_key where a`.assigned_to="office" and `u`.`id="53"`

Comment: exactly assignee_key.

Answer (score 0):

You have got two select. Here is the better/structured version of your query.

```
$this->db->select("a.*")
             ->from("address as a")
             ->join("user","user.id = a.assignee_key","left")
             ->where(array("a.assigned_to"=>"office","user.id"=>$user_id));         
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->row();
```

UPDATE: For the comment try left outer join

```
->join("user","user.id = a.assignee_key","left outer")
```

*It preserves the unmatched rows from the first (left) table, joining them with a NULL row in the shape of the second (right) table.*

Comment: thanks, no error. but i want to display a result if no data in address table with user_id, means if i dont have records with user_id in address table i need to display empty records,but am getting                               Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Try left outer in place of left then.

Comment: I have tried with  left outer  but getting same error.

Comment: Change @NabinKunwar code bit ... change from `user` and join with `address` table. and no need of `left outer join`.

Comment: Just like @Yash said select from user and join to address table

Comment: controller: $user_office_address = $this->UserModel->user_office_address($user_id);                                                    Model:     function user_office_address($user_id) {
        $this->db->select("address.*")
                ->from("user")
                ->join("address","user.id = address.assignee_key")
                ->where(array("address.assigned_to" => "office", "user.id" => $user_id));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();}  View:<?php echo $user_office_address->first_line; ?>, <?php echo $user_office_address->second_line; ?>

Comment: How are you sending your data to view? How are you calling your view with data? May be you are not passing anything.

Comment: $data = array(
            'site_theme' => $theme,
            'data' => $user_data,
            'user_detail' => $user_details,
            'user_home_address' => $user_home_address,
            'user_office_address' => $user_office_address,
            'user_default_address' => $user_default_address,
            'list_user_address' => $list_user_address
        );

        $this->load->view("$this->site_theme/site/user/profile", $data);
    }

Comment: @Sunilkumarm What errors you are getting ..? Please update complete code on your question.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: user/profile.php

Line Number: 92

Backtrace:

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\EdocStaffing\Web\application\views\Canvas\site\user\profile.php
Line: 92
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\EdocStaffing\Web\application\controllers\User.php
Line: 62
Function: view

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\EdocStaffing\Web\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: what is `$this->site_theme` in controller ..?

Comment: i have used tepmlate name. i am fetching template name  form database.